# Javascript Get Promise Result from Callback

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, promise

How can i get via promise the data from a callback function?
Is that possible?

Here is my Code:

```
var bricklets = [];
var ipcon = new Tinkerforge.IPConnection();
pcon.on(Tinkerforge.IPConnection.CALLBACK_ENUMERATE, function(uid, connectedUid, position, hardwareVersion, firmwareVersion, deviceIdentifier, enumerationType) {
    if (enumerationType === Tinkerforge.IPConnection.ENUMERATION_TYPE_DISCONNECTED) {
        console.log('');
        return;
    }
    bricklets.push(new Bricklet(uid, deviceIdentifier, connectedUid));
});
```

I know that this solution will not work, but i dont have any idea to get the data outside the function via promise.

Comment: If you just want to learn how to use promises, have a look at at http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

Comment: Why are you using console.log('') is this the place where you expect to manipulate your data?

Answer (score 2):

Since your callback is called back multiple times, it is a bit more complicated than just [promisifying your API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) by passing `resolve`/`reject` as callbacks to your method.

You'd call `resolve` with the array of results once the last call was made:

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var bricklets = [];
    var ipcon = new Tinkerforge.IPConnection();
    pcon.on(Tinkerforge.IPConnection.CALLBACK_ENUMERATE, function(uid, connectedUid, position, hardwareVersion, firmwareVersion, deviceIdentifier, enumerationType) {
        if (enumerationType === Tinkerforge.IPConnection.ENUMERATION_TYPE_DISCONNECTED) {
            return resolve(bricklets); // when done
//                 ^^^^^^^
        } // else if some error happened
            // return reject(err);
        bricklets.push(new Bricklet(uid, deviceIdentifier, connectedUid));
    });
});
```

Now, you don't really get your data "out of the callback" in the sense that they would be synchronously returned ([promises are still async callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572)), but you get a `promise` *for the data* that is much easier to work with than using callbacks.

You might consume it like

```
promise.then(function(bricklets) {
    console.log(bricklets);
    … // do more
}); // returns a new promise for the result of "do more"
```